# Python UDF in Redshift fast with CTE than direct select query

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have a function written in python for redshift, code below (calculates business days between two dates "South African Holidays and weekends"):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION b_days (start_date timestamp, end_date timestamp)
RETURNS INTEGER IMMUTABLE as $$
    from pandas import date_range
    from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday
```

the code is super quick when test on

> - Jupyter Notebook
> - run function on a simple select: `select business_days('2018-06-29','2018-07-02')` return 2 as answer
> - using CTE
>     `with cte as(
>     select id, sdate, edate
>     from bigtable --with million rows
>     )
>     select id, sdate, edate, business_days(sdate,edate)
>     from cte`

but it runs non stop when i say:

```
select id, sdate, edate, business_days(sdate,edate)
from bigtable --with million rows
```

Comment: Are you saying that, in exactly the same environment, it runs quickly using `WITH cte` but slow without the `with`? (That is, both methods are via the Notebook, only difference is the SQL used?)

Comment: If you are sure about what you have put, check the performance graphs on redshift aws console while its running non stop to see what is running. This might be one for AWS support. my understanding is that in redshift, a cte is exactly like implementing as a sub-select.

Comment: Apparently, today the function is running flawlessly and no errors. makes me wonder if redshift was caching it or something